# how to fix HTTP ERROR 405 in Django form?

Tags: django

there
I'm using Django 1.9. I'm watching thenewboston Django lessons with bucky
now when I'm trying to test this form it doesn't work. when I lunch the code is already running but when send the form it gives me this page. so, if anyone knows about the solution!
**note**: I imitate every single code he does with the same version for Django. so, what's going on?

[image]

views.py

```
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic import View
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from .models import Album, Song
from .forms import UserForm


class HomeView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'music/index.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Album.objects.all()


class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Album
    template_name = 'music/details.html'


class AlbumCreate(CreateView):
    model = Album
    fields = ['artist', 'album_title', 'genre', 'album_logo']


class AlbumUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Album
    fields = ['artist', 'album_title', 'genre', 'album_logo']


class AlbumDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Album
    # where are you going when you delete this element from page
    success_url = reverse_lazy('music:home')


class SongView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'music/song.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Song.objects.all()


class CreateSong(CreateView):
    model = Song # will affects on this model
    fields = ['album', 'file_type', 'song_title'] # model fields

    # You have used get_absolute_url in models.py so you cannot using it again until no errors wrong
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('music:songs')
    # So the question is: where are the fields that will return these fields?
    # answer is: you will create Html file which called song_form and that contains all fields you hold


class UserFormView(View):
    form_class = UserForm
    template_name = 'music/registration.html'


    def get(self, request):
        # Empty value
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})


    def set(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            # If form is True catch the form that came by POST without saving it
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            # cleaned_data allow to check if any field has errors or it's Normalized data
            # check data automatically by Django
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            # make the password field not visual
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            # If the given credentials are valid, return a User object
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            # Check if user has logged in or not
            if user is not None: # -> so, it was post
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('music:home')
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'music'

urlpatterns = [
    # /music/
    url(r"^$", views.HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    # /music/register/
    url(r"^register/$", views.UserFormView.as_view(), name='register'),
    # /music/123/
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='details'),
    # /album/add/
    url(r'^album/add/$', views.AlbumCreate.as_view(), name='add-album'),
    # /album/123/
    url(r'^album/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.AlbumUpdate.as_view(), name='update-album'),
    # /album/123/delete/
    url(r'^album/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/$', views.AlbumDelete.as_view(), name='delete-album'),
    # /music/song/
    url(r'^song/$', views.SongView.as_view(), name='songs'),
    # /music/song/
    url(r'^song/add/$', views.CreateSong.as_view(), name='add-song'),
]
```

registration.html

```
{% extends 'music/base.html' %}
{% block body %}

    <div class="album-form">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <h2>Create a new account</h2>
                            <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                {% include 'music/form-template.html' %}
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: share your views and HTMl code

Comment: Yes, it will be helpful for us to answer if you share your codes.

Comment: please share error log.

Comment: sorry i don't know how i missed that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTTP 405 error code means the HTTP method used is not supported. Your form is submitted via HTTP POST, but the `post()` method on the view shown is not implemented, so it cannot handle POST requests. The form submission needs to be handled in the `post()` method.

Comment: ok, I understand now but how to fix that issue?
is that special with a chrome version? if it's around the Django version then how it works with him not with me? it's the same version I use
could u help?

Comment: It's nothing to do with Chrome. You define a `post()` method on the view for that route and put the code to handle the form submission there. It looks like you already have that in your `set()` method, so you need to rename it. With Django's class based views it calls the method that matches the HTTP verb used.

Comment: yes, it works with me
thank u Matthew sorry for tired you